# Is it possible to match attribute from another element and retrieve its content?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

When I'm in : `<xsl:template match="listOfPerson/person">`

for person of id "A", is it possible to retrieve his information that is stored in another element here it's inside the element data

xml :

```
<root>
    <data>
        <person id="A">
            <name> Anna </name>
            <age> 1 </age>
        </person>
        <person id="B">
            <name> Banana </name>
            <age> 1 </age>
        </person>
    </data>

    <listOfPerson>
        <person>
            <id>A</id>
        </person>
        <person>
            <id>B</id>
        </person>
    </listOfPerson>
</root>
```

my current xsl :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="listOfPerson/person"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="listOfPerson/person">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

current output :

```
A
B
```

desired output :

```
Anna 1
Banana 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT has a built-in [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key) mechanism for resolving cross-references. Consider the following example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="person" match="data/person" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="listOfPerson/person">
        <xsl:variable name="data" select="key('person', id)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$data/name" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$data/age" />
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
 Anna   1 
 Banana   1
```